# If Gray Merchant dies and is revived by something like Undying Evil, does it repeat it's loss of life when it is revived?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Gray Merchant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gray%20Merchant) dies and is revived by something like [Undying Evil](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Undying%20Evil), does it repeat it's loss of life when it is revived?

Also, if you used a card like [Twilight's Call](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=338399) and he was revived with a bunch of other black creatures would the other revived black creatures count towards your devotion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1. Yes, he enters the battle field and thus his ability triggers.

Question 2: Yes, you use the devotion at the time the spell resolves.

A ruling on [Gray merchant of asphodel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373645) has this:

> If an activated ability or triggered ability has an effect that
>   depends on your devotion to a color, you count the number of mana
>   symbols of that color among the mana costs of permanents you control
>   as the ability resolves. The permanent with that ability will be
>   counted if it’s still on the battlefield at that time.